# How to remove lines from string which has nothing except a blank newline?

Tags: string, vb.net, trim

I have two **`TextBoxes`** in my form with **`Multiline`** enabled and a **`Button`**. Lets say **`tB1`** and **`tB2`**. **`tB1`**  and **`tB2`** consist  group numbers and the **`Button`** click event removes all the string (numbers) from the **`tB1`** that are present on **`tB2`**. But as all the numbers are being separated by **`NewLine`** replacing the string by matching with with another string causes a lots of blank lines between.

Example -**`tB1`** Values:

> 1
>
> 2
>
> 3
>
> 4
>
> 5
>
> 6
>
> 7
>
> 8
>
> 9
>
> 10

Example -**`tB2`** Values:

> 3
>
> 7
>
> 8

What I am getting:

> 1
>
> 2
>
> [Blank Line]
>
> 4
>
> 5
>
> 6
>
> [Blank Line]
>
> [Blank Line]
>
> 9
>
> 10

What I want it to be:

> 1
>
> 2
>
> 4
>
> 5
>
> 6
>
> 9
>
> 10

I am using the code:

```
Dim strFix() as String

Private Sub Button1_Click() Handles Button1.Click
    strFix = Split(tB2.Text, vbNewLine)
    For Each str1 as String In strFix
        tb1.Text= tb1.Text.Replace(str1, "")
    Next
End Sub
```

Note: Using .Trim() didn't solved this as it only removes the last blank lines or spaces.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I have found a solution that worked for me.

```
Dim strFix() As String

Private Sub FixBlankLines ()
    strFix = Split(tB2.Text, vbNewLine)
    For Each str1 as String In strFix
        tb1.Text= tb1.Text.Replace(str1, "")
    Next
    strFix = Split(tb1.Text, vbNewLine)
    tb1.Text = ""
    For Each str2 As String In strFix
        If str2 <> "" Then
             tb1.Text += Val(str2).ToString("00000") + vbNewLine
        End If
    Next
    tb1.Text = tb1.Text.Trim
End Sub
```

Answer (score 4):

`String.Replace` doesn't help to remove those lines. You have to create a new line-list without those which appear in Tb2.

You can use [`TextBox.Lines`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textboxbase.lines(v=vs.110).aspx) to get an array of all lines. LINQ simplifies the task:

```
Dim onlyInTb1 = tB1.Lines.Except(tB2.Lines)
tB1.Lines = onlyInTb1.ToArray()
```

The classic non-LINQ way is to use a `List(Of String)`:

```
Dim onlyInTb1List As New List(Of String)
Dim tb2Lines = tb2.Lines
For Each tb1Line In tB1.Lines
    If Not tb2Lines.Contains(tb1Line) 
        onlyInTb1List.Add(tb1Line)
    End If
Next
tb1.Lines = onlyInTb1List.ToArray()
```

Finally an approach without the `textBox.Lines`-"trick" with `String.Split` and `String.Join`:

```
Dim tb1Lines = tB1.Text.Split({Environment.NewLine}, StringSplitOptions.None)
Dim tb2Lines = tB2.Text.Split({Environment.NewLine}, StringSplitOptions.None)
Dim onlyInTb1 = tb1Lines.Except( tb2Lines )
tB1.Text = String.Join(Environment.NewLine, onlyInTb1)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is happening because of the For Each loop. It is "doubling up" this code each time it cycles through an item.

Comment: No mate, I don't think so that's the problem. Actually that was happening because the array contains one a string and not new line so when I replace the string is getting replace keeping the new line alone in the line :D

Answer (score 0):

```
txtResult.Lines = txtSource.Lines.Where(Function(line) line.Trim() <> String.Empty).ToArray()
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.